# how to use relative link in codeigniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter

I have the following code in Controller:

```
    class Home extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('home');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('layout');

    }

    function about()
    {
        $this->load->view('about');
    }
}
```

If I want to create a relative link to about, how do I accomplish that? The following link in view doesn't always work. What is apporpiate way to about relative links in CodeIngiter?

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('application/views/about'); ?>"> About </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason your view code doesn't work is most likely due to not autoloading the URL Helper.

If you add the 'url' to the Autoloader (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) the function `site_url` will become available on all controllers, views, and models.

---

File to edit: application / config / autoload.php

Line 110

Example of what it should look like (assuming you aren't auto-loading any other helpers):

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Answer (score 0):

link should be name_of_controller/name_of_the_function

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>home/about"> About </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('home/about'); ?>"> About </a></li>
```

Comment: which url is print please tell so i more help you.

Comment: @user3040085 please try this base_url('home/about');

Comment: i try base_url('home/about') but page not found

Answer (score 0):

Auto load your url helper and try

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/about'); ?>"> About </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the anchor() function.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

```
<li><?php echo anchor('home/about', 'About') ?></li>
```

Use that in your view.

**Updated**